# Django forms: how to use a query to show right options

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = RichTextField (
        verbose_name = 'Question'
        )
    QUESTION_TYPE = (
        ('Multi', 'Multiple Choice (one correct answer)'),
        ('Check', 'Multiple Answers')
    )
    question_type = models.CharField(
        default         = "Multi",
        max_length      = 7,
        verbose_name    = "Question Type",
        choices         = QUESTION_TYPE)

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, 
        help_text       = 'Category for this Question',
        null            = True
        )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
    )
    quiz = models.ForeignKey (
        Quiz,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

I am trying to use a Django form with it so I have this form:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id','question_type','category','name','author','quiz',]
        widgets = {'id': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'author': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'quiz': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'question_type' :forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'category' :forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

It works fine except the Category model is associated to a specific Quiz and I only want Categories for the Quiz to which the Question is linked.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (
        max_length = 30,
        verbose_name = "Question Categories",
    )
    quiz = models.ForeignKey (
        Quiz,
        verbose_name = 'Quiz',
    )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

I am trying to work out how to limit the `Category` models presented to the user through the form but I cannot work out how.  Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like below:

```
q_info = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
Q = QuestionForm(instance=q_info)
Q.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(condition)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you